# Implement custom search by term name(s) in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, search

I have implemented normal search functionality in simple pages using php and MySQL where I get result rows by mysqli_fetch_array. There I could have any numbers of variable with AND or OR relationship and it will retrieve results from the db.
Now I am trying to do this in WordPress.
I have seen solutions where one uses WP_query to search by term names. How do I achieve this AND and OR variables in my search query.

For example, my query is like select all post title where term name like 'search keyword' AND term slug like 'hi'.

I have created a view terms_and_posts table from merging terms and posts tables using taxonomy relationship, with columns custom term name, custom term slug, post title, post content, post status, and post type.

Do I need a merged table or it can be achieved by modifying WP_Query?

I do not want to resort to using plugins as I am very new to WordPress, and I prefer not to use plugins as long as I can help it.

Comment: Your see https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters by term name and post_content, post_status  https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter, if your need custom query in WP_Query your use https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where

Comment: @Guillermo Andres Fuentes Moral, I will look into these functions more thoroughly and WordPress code reference as well.